# how to center align td cell or table in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, mobile, html-table, responsive

```css
.button-center {
  max-width: 100% !important;
  min-width: 100px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%" align="center" dir="ltr" valign="top" style="max-width:100%;">
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: left; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px;  color: #000;">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="height:24px;" height="24"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">
        <table cellpadding="0" class="button-center" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background-color:#9E2776;max-width:100%;" align="left">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>

                <a href="" style="color:ffffff;padding:10 10;font-family: Arial;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;display: block;border-collapse: collapse;font-weight: bold;">Lorem Ipsum</a>
              </td>

            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table> 
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining `display: inline-block` for that cell (`.button-center`), which works against the whole principle of automatic table formating. Just delete that and the contents of that cell/table will center:

```css
.button-center {
  max-width: 100% !important;
  min-width: 100px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%" align="center" dir="ltr" valign="top" style="max-width:100%;">
  <tbody>


    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: left; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px;  color: #000;">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="height:24px;" height="24"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">
        <table cellpadding="0" class="button-center" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background-color:#9E2776;max-width:100%;" align="left">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>

                <a href="" style="color:ffffff;padding:10 10;font-family: Arial;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;display: block;border-collapse: collapse;font-weight: bold;">Lorem Ipsum</a>
              </td>

            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```